# Incorrect return value from function in command line

Tags: python, function, command-line-interface

I am calling a python function from CLI. The function is supposed to return an array. But instead I get boolean 'True' as output after running the below command. Do I need to add some other command to print array to the CLI or is this an issue with my function itself?

```
python -c 'from laser import Laser; laser = Laser(); laser.embed_sentences("hello", lang = "en").shape == (1, 1024);'
```

The laser.embed_sentences returns an array but all I see is 'True' after running this command. Please help

Comment: The expression you're evaluating is `laser.embed_sentences("hello", lang = "en").shape == (1, 1024)` which is true or false. If you don't want that, you could take the `.shape == (1, 1024)` off the end.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your last line is

```
laser.embed_sentences("hello", lang = "en").shape == (1, 1024)
```

which checks if `laser.embed_sentences("hello", lang = "en").shape` is equivalent to the array (tuple) `(1, 1024)`. And you say it returns `True`.

So, yes, `laser.embed_sentences("hello", lang = "en").shape` is returning the array `(1, 1024)`. But you are not printing that. You are checking if that array is equivalent to the array `(1, 1024)`. which is True. So it shows True.

Remove the `== (1, 1024)` to get the array.